# Can't get rid of a disk partition on mac

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, disk-utility, disk-space

I have a base model MacBook Pro with M1 and 256gib of storage. I tried macOS Ventura and it was fine, but I didn't like it much so I reverted to Monterey by adding a partition and installing it here. Today I wanted to remove the old partitions but they couldn’t unmount and begone.

What should I do?

Comment: Edit your question and add the output from the command `diskutil list`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the **Disk Utility** application.

You can find it in the Utilities folder which is in Applications folder: [How to resize disk partition in macOS](https://www.macworld.com/article/230826/how-to-resize-disk-partition-in-macos.html)

Comment: Usually macOS is installed on the second partition of a drive. If the users shrunk this partition to create a new third partition, then the Disk Utility application would not be able to remove the old second partition. In other words, the `-` button would be grayed out when the old second partition is highlighted in the pie chart. (Note: The first partition is the EFI partition, which is the Disk Utility hides and therefore does not appear in the pie chart.)